# Is there a bug in the user reputation league table?

Tags: discussion, bug, reputation, reputation-leagues

Today, while going through the [user reputation league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2015-05-01/), I found one user with

- Total reputation : 3,494
- Month reputation : 3,513.

**TL;DR : This month rep point is more than total rep**

Screenshot:
[image: User Rep League screenshot]

My simple question: How (why) is this possible? Is it a bug?

Comment: @fishbelowtheice thanks for the dupe.

Comment: @shadowwizard Thanks, so it's happenning all the time, we're not noticing it. Just in case of the new user, it's prominent. :-)